# Completion of the unit group of a local field

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathfrak{p}$ a finite prime of $K$. Denote the unit group of the ring of integers of the local field $K_\mathfrak{p}$ (i.e. the completion of $K$ via $\mathfrak{p}$) by $U_\mathfrak{p}$. For an archimedian prime we set $U_\mathfrak{p} = K^\times_\mathfrak{p}$.

Now for a rational prime $p$ and an abelian group $A$ denote by $\hat A$ the $p$-completion, i.e.

$$\hat A = \lim_{\begin{matrix} \leftarrow \\ n\end{matrix}} A / p^n A$$

Now the claim is that for $\mathfrak{p} \not\mid p$ the completion $\hat U_\mathfrak{p}$ is finite. Can somebody help me with a hint?

Thank you!

Tom

Comment: For the sake of clarity, you might want to change $p$ by $q$ (because usually $\mathfrak{p}$ *is* a prime above $p$), and denote your abelian group multiplicatively.

Comment: What is an archimedean prime? Is it an archimedean absolute value, i.e. $|•|_∞$? Interpreting absolute values as primes?

Comment: Thanks for your comments so far: I took the definitions above directly from a standard book in number theory. I must disagree: $\mathfrak{p}$ is imho not an exclusive notation for a prime above $p$. What do you mean with abelian notation? I think it is clear what the $p$-completion means in that case? An archimedean prime is an infinite place, i.e. an embedding of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, interpreted as prime, yes :-)

Comment: While $\mathfrak{p}$ is not an exclusive notation for a prime above $p$, it is usually the case. I would be curious to see a research paper or book where both $\mathfrak{p}$ and $p$ appear in the same paragraph, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is not a prime above $p$. Do you have one in mind?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo If you read for example "Cohomology of Number Fields" of Neukirch et. al. you really often get confronted with primes $\mathfrak{p}$ that are part of a set $S$ without $S$ being necessarily the set $S_p$ of all primes above $p$. (cf. (10.5.1), Riemann's Existence Theorem)

Comment: I don't think the example provided is quite what I was asking for. One thing is to write about a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in a set of primes $S$ (some of which *are* above $p$), and something completely different is to make a statement about a single prime $\mathfrak{p}$ which is not above $p$. The latter is simply confusing notation. There is no need to name both prime ideals using variations of the letter "p" if we can avoid it. And indeed this can be easily avoided by renaming $p$ by $q$.

Comment: My answer below illustrates my point. When $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $K$, then the prime ideal is generated by some rational prime of $\mathbb{Z}$. If I was to stick with your notation, should I have said $\mathfrak{p}=(q)$ for some prime $q$? That would have been very awkward.

Comment: Ahh.. maybe I now get the problem. With "unit group of local field" I meant the the units of unique ring of integers of the local field. I thought this is common knowledge. So, in your example below you have $U_p = \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. I've edited the post above!

Comment: The unit group of a field is the field except 0. The unit group of the ring of integers in a local or number field is not the unit group of the field. Even if this was "common knowledge", it is misleading terminology and it should be avoided. It is best to write precisely what one means. I figured that's what you actually meant, and that's why I wrote "This is false **as stated**"

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo Ok, thank you! I was being mislead by the terminology the authors use in "Cohomology of number field" - don't be too hard on me at this one! Do you still think, it is a wrong statement?

Comment: No problem. Is the new statement correct? You will find out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put an end to the "quarrel" on notations, let *p* be a fixed prime number and *v* a "place" of a number field *K* (in the usual language of algebraic number theory), $K_v$ the completion of *K* at *v*, $k_v$ its residue field, which is a finite field of characterisic *q* (the prime number underlying *v*). For any  natural integer *n* , let $U_n$ be the subgroup of $K_v$* defined by : *x* belongs to $U_n$ iff *v(1-x)* is at least *n*. Then $U_0$ is the group of local units, $U_0$/$U_1$ is isomorphic to $k_v$* (multiplicative group) and, for *n* at least $1$, $U_n$/$U_{n+1}$ is isomorphic to $k_v$ (additive group). This is classical and easily shown by taking residual classes; see e.g. Cassels-Fröhlich's book "Algebraic Number Theory", chapter 1, propos. 4. But $k_v$* is finite and, if *q* is different from *p*, by using the above description of $U_n$/$U_{n+1}$ , a straightforward approximation argument shows that the map *u* -> $u^m$ , *m* = a power of *p* , is an automorphism of $U_1$ ; see *op.* *cit.* propos. 5. It follows at once that the *p*-adic completion of $U_0$ is equal to that of $k_v$* , hence is finite .

Answer (score 2):

This was false as originally stated, and a proof is below. The OP has since changed the statement.

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}$, let $p$ be a rational prime, and let $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$. Let $U_p=\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, and let $q$ be a prime distinct from $p$. Let $n\geq 1$ be arbitrary, consider $\widehat{U}_{p,q,n}=U_p/U_p^{q^n}$, and consider the subgroup $B_n$ of $\widehat{U}_{p,q,n}$ generated by $p$. Since $p$ is not a $q$th power in $\mathbb{Q}_p^\times$, it follows that the subgroup $B_n$ has size $q^n$, and it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, 
$$\widehat{U}_{p,q} = \varprojlim U_{p,q,n}$$
has a subgroup $B=\varprojlim B_n$ isomorphic to $\varprojlim \mathbb{Z}/q^n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}_q$. In particular, $\widehat{U}_{p,q}$ is infinite.

Comment: Corrected the notation, so $U_p = \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$, therefore the argument might be wrong.

Comment: Ok, so try the same approach. What is $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times/(\mathbb{Z}_p^\times)^{q^n}$?

Comment: Or a simpler question, what is $(\mathbb{Z}/p^m\mathbb{Z})^\times$ modulo $q^n$th powers?

Comment: It is $\mathbb{Z}/p^m-1 q^n \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: First of all $\varphi(p^m)=(p-1)p^{m-1}$.

Comment: So it's $\mathbb{Z} / ((p-1)p^{m-1}q^n) \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What units modulo $5$ are $3$rd powers? Does that match your formula at all?